# Difference between timestamps Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am trying to run a query but in a part of code that calculate the diference between two timestamps the error below is showed.

1878. 00000 -  "specified field not found in datetime or interval"
      *Cause:    The specified field was not found in the datetime or interval.
      *Action:   Make sure that the specified field is in the datetime or interval

Part of code:

SYSTIMESTAMP - DT_PROP

The type of DT_PROP is TIMESTAMP(6).

I will be thankfull if someone can send me a suggestion to solve this.

Comment: Why do you think the error is thrown from that specific "part of code"? I suspect it may be thrown by other parts of the code (perhaps not far from this computation), not by the computation itself. For example - how is the result of this computation used in the rest of the query?

Comment: Hi Mathguy, I guess this because I maked comments in the others parts of query and when I run only whithout this part the query run without errors

Comment: extract(day from (SYSTIMESTAMP - DT_PROP)) * 24 * 60 +
  extract(hour from (SYSTIMESTAMP - DT_PROP)) * 60 +
  extract(minute from (SYSTIMESTAMP - DT_PROP)) AS TEMPO

Comment: This is the part of query that issue an error. I'm sure that isn't a sintax error...

Comment: It is not a syntax error - you only got it when you executed the query. I figured out what's happening (I think) - see the answer I posted. If all the timestamps were valid in your system's time zone, you would not get any errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225176/discussion-between-wilson-jimenez-and-mathguy).

Answer (score 1):

Here is what's happening.

SYSTIMESTAMP is a timestamp WITH TIME ZONE. DT_PROP is a timestamp (without time zone). You are taking the difference between two values of different data types.

Oracle will not throw an error; it will make an implicit conversion. Converting from timestamp with time zone to a simple timestamp will lose information; so, Oracle won't do that. Instead, Oracle does the opposite: it up-casts the timestamp (DT_PROP) to a timestamp with time zone. For this, it must make an assumption: it assumes the time zone is the same as your system time zone.

And then it runs into trouble, if your system time zone is DST-aware (daylight saving time) and if the pure timestamp (without time zone) is invalid in that DST-aware time zone.

For example, in Los Angeles (U.S.A), daylight saving time in 2020 began on March 8 - the clock was moved forward one hour at 2 A.M. - meaning that, in one-second intervals, the time right after 01:59:59 was 03:00:00. A time-of-day of 02:30:00, for example, on the date 2020-03-08, simply did not exist.

This is one of the cases when Oracle will throw the exact error you reported. And it is entirely possible that it's the reason it threw it from your code.

Solutions? There are some; but you have a DATA PROBLEM. If the timestamps stored in DT_PROP are **supposed** to represent times in your DST-aware time zone, and you have an invalid value stored in the column, what's up with that? It's easy to write code around it, but shouldn't your business user be alerted to this first? I believe they should. Then see what they tell you - HOW they want this to be handled; otherwise you would be making a **business** decision for them, not just a "programming" decision.